# Root FS always full: /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log flooding

Tags: filesystem, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 when it came out, on a brand new computer that I just bought. I have been a user of Ubuntu Gnome for a few years, so this is nothing but routine now. However, I get messages of my root partition (i.e. `/`) being full every now and then. Using the disk usage tool, I see that `/var/log` is the culprit.

For example, `df -h` outputs

```
$ df -h
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev               7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs              1,6G    170M  1,4G  11% /run
/dev/sda2           39G     37G     0 100% /
tmpfs              7,9G    186M  7,7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs              7,9G       0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          476M    3,6M  472M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4          863G    790M  818G   1% /home
tmpfs              1,6G     20K  1,6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs              1,6G     48K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Once I delete all in `/var/log`, I get

```
$ sudo rm -Rf /var/log/*
$ df -h
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev               7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs              1,6G    170M  1,4G  11% /run
/dev/sda2           39G     32G  5,2G  86% /
tmpfs              7,9G    186M  7,7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs              7,9G       0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          476M    3,6M  472M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4          863G    790M  818G   1% /home
tmpfs              1,6G     20K  1,6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs              1,6G     48K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

However, if I reboot my computer, the usage will be quite different, reporting a more "normal" usage, and a lot more free space.

```
$ df -h
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev               7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs              1,6G     58M  1,6G   4% /run
/dev/sda2           39G    4,7G   32G  13% /
tmpfs              7,9G    324K  7,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs              7,9G       0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          476M    3,6M  472M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4          863G    775M  818G   1% /home
tmpfs              1,6G     12K  1,6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs              1,6G     32K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

**Note**: this is a vanilla installation of Ubuntu Gnome. There is **no way** that it would use so much space at it is reported.

#### Question

Why is `/var/log` eating up *so much* space? What makes it log 25GB+ of data regularly? This never happened before.

I am aware of space usage reported vs actual spaced used, but this is ridiculously different. And I keep my system up-to-date at all times, running `apt-get` regularly.

Thank you.

---

## Update

---

This issue is so weird. I don't understand the problem. Well, one image is worth a thousand words, so... here it is

[Print screen of my "empty" drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxl9y.png)

And I have been checking [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/490704/ubuntu-server-hard-drive-always-full) answer, but it does not tell why this happen and how to fix it. Meanwhile, here is what I get from the command :

```
# lsof +L1
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE    SIZE/OFF NLINK     NODE NAME
rsyslogd    629 syslog    5w   REG    8,2 17066459136     0  1059065 /var/log/syslog (deleted)
rsyslogd    629 syslog    6w   REG    8,2 17066283008     0  1059066 /var/log/kern.log (deleted)
rsyslogd    629 syslog    7w   REG    8,2        8192     0  1059068 /var/log/auth.log (deleted)
Xorg        888   root    0w   REG    8,2       21882     0  1059142 /var/log/Xorg.0.log (deleted)
Xorg       1280   root    0w   REG    8,2       21731     0  1059150 /var/log/Xorg.1.log (deleted)
```

---

## Update 2

---

From [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/403738/after-deleting-log-files-ubuntu-server-still-saying-there-is-no-space) answer, so I can solve this issue with `sudo service rsyslog restart`. (Yay!)

But why?? Why does `syslog` fail?

---

## Update 3

---

```
# ll /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 16860587310 mai 13 07:25 /var/log/syslog
# tail /var/log/syslog
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.521432] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.522528] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.522530] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8804558d89d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.522532] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.523563] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.523565] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8804558d89d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.523567] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.524946] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.524948] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8804558d89d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
May 13 07:25:33 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41665.524965] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

# ll /var/log/kern.log 
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 16887690761 mai 13 07:26 /var/log/kern.log
# tail /var/log/kern.log 
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.722995] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.724098] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.724100] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8804558d89d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.724103] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.725134] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.725136] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8804558d89d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.725138] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.726578] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.726580] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8804558d89d8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
May 13 07:26:37 PC-Sylvie kernel: [41728.726597] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
```

**Note:** restarting `syslog` does not fix the issue, and I have to manually delete the files.

Comment: Which log file is growing?  What is the (repeated ?) error message?

Comment: I will attempt to monitor and get which file(s) is/are growing. As for the error message, it's the notification message letting me know that my disk is full. (Probably getting this when apt's cron job is trying to fetch updates.)

Comment: du -hs * | sort -h is a good way to list everything in a directory and sort it from small to large; a few iterations of that, and you'll quickly get to the specific directory and file that's eating space.

Comment: Your kernel appears to be spewing millions of error messages.  Take a look at what is in /var/log/syslog and see what it is complaining about.

Comment: I got this suggestion from somewhere else, but it's worth a try: `sudo echo disable > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F` may stop the flood of error messages.

Comment: This seem to work! If you can put that into an answer, with some explanations, that'd be great! .... and a probable accepted answer for you :)